# clip-path polygon rounded edge

Tags: html, css, sass, clip-path

I am trying to round the bottom right corner of a div while also slanting the bottom of the div. My understanding is that you can't necessarily use ellipse in conjunction with polygon and am looking for some guidance on how to accomplish this.

I'm able to create the slant, however the slant doesn't exactly line up well with the rounded edge using `border-radius`. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.test {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  .bg {
    background: orange;
    width: 100%;
    height: 483px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 120px 0;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 92%, 0 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 92%, 0 100%);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d6u5bfej/3/

Comment: You can't do this with a `polygon`, (they don't have curves) you need a `path` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57382396/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/61768893/8620333

Comment: So using `clip-path: ellipse(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 92%, 0 100%);` does not work for you? I just checked it and it looks pretty good in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps you.
It was solved with the before pseudo-class and tranform skewy.

**SCSS:**

```
.test {
position: relative;
width: 75%;
height: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 483px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

.bg:before {
    content: "";
    position:  absolute;
    background: orange;
    z-index: -1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 120px;
    transform: skewy(-4deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
  }
```

}

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto; }
  .test .bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 483px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0; }
  .test .bg:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: orange;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 120px;
    transform: skewy(-4deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom; }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test">
            <div class="bg"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wish I could give 100 up's for this answer, this helped so much! For anyone curious, you don't necessarily need the .test outer container, but it helps to create a fixed-width boundary. Otherwise, you'll have to use a margin since surrounding elements won't respect the full shape.